# squirrel sql client settings folder location

Tags: installation, squirrel-sql

I installed the squirrel client 3.4.0 on my windows 7 64 bit machine.

I see a squirrel client settings folder

> ".squirrel-sql"

created in:

> C:\Users\ayusman\

Is there any way I can specify the folder location to be in my squirrel install location i.e.

> "C:\tools\dumps\Squirrel-3.4.0"

location?

The reason I want to do this is to make my squirrel set up easily movable between machines; I could just take the dump of the application and I will be ready to go on any machine.

Also is there a Squirrel-sql distribution that does not do the installation; but rather just a simple zip file that I can unzip to any location and start working?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**About the local settings directory of SQuirreL:**

SQuirrel SQL is an application written in Java and it uses the Java System Property `user.home` to store the local configuration files. Per default, this Java Property points to the home directory of the user. You can change this by the following steps:

Open squirrel-sql.bat in a text editor and navigate to the end of the file. One of the last lines should start with "start "SQuirreL SQL Client" - you have to change this line. Add `-Duser.home=PathToStoreTheSquirrelConfigDir` just after the -Xmx argument and ensure, that the new Argument is separated by a space from the others.

Here an example:

```
 -Xmx256m -Duser.home=C:/temp -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

Note, that I use the slash and not a back-slash!

Now you can move the existing .squirrel-sql directory to the new place.
e.g `C:\temp\.squirrel-sql`

Now, if you start SQuirreL SQL, it will use the new storage location. You can verify this in the global properties of SQuirrel (see the section SQuirreL paths)

**About the installer version of SQuirreL:**

SQuirreL SQL also offers a plain zip instead of a installer version.  [Here is the link to the latest stable version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrel-sql/files/1-stable/3.4.0-plainzip/)

SQuirreL is offering 3 packages (base, standard, optional). The difference between them are the packaged plugins. I use the optional package - but the standard package is also fine.

Comment: SQuirreL SQL connection aliases location: `%USERPROFILE%\.squirrel-sql\SQLAliases23.xml`

Comment: Is there any way to do this through the shortcut that is pointing to `squirrel-sql.bat`? (i.e. without modifying the `squirrel-sql.bat`). Like `...\squirrel-sql.bat "-Duser.home=C:/temp"`. As far as I can see, `squirrel-sql.bat` accepts parameters, but they are all set at the end of the command line, and thus not correctly (?) interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Squirrel-Parameter `--user-settings-dir`, but unlinke the other answer with `-Duser.home` you have to use the actual Squirrel-Settings-Directory, e.g. the one with all the xml-Settings files and the folders logs and plugins.

You can use that parameter on the .jar / main-class directly, but also on the `squirrel-sql.bat` or `squirrel-sql.sh` file, so you don't need to edit those.

Example:

```
C:\dev\squirrel-sql\squirrel-sql-3.9.0\squirrel-sql.bat --user-settings-dir=C:\dev\squirrel-sql\squirrel-sql-settings
```

This is from the Squirrel-Manual, strangly enough, i couldn't find an online-source for it (only an outdated one), buts inside the squirrel installation folder, e.g. `squirrel-sql-3.9.0/doc/quick_start.html`

Comment: This is perfect to both keep settings for different versions and gives ability to move configuration directory from `$HOME` to `$HOME/.config` (where it is supposed to be in `Linux`)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can make whole settings directory portable using argument `--user-settings-dir  "%CD%\settings"` in the link to .bat file.

Thus in the `Target` of your link you will get something like this:
`"C:\...\squirrelsql\squirrel-sql.bat" --user-settings-dir  "%CD%\settings"`